# cordova platform add ios issue

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

[image][image]

When I add ios platform always getting an error like

Cordova platform add ios --save Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-Cordova module "q" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it. [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess Cordova.

How to fix this problem?

I have already installed the npm install -g cordova@8.1.1.

Comment: can you add screenshot and ionic info

Comment: Are you running `cordova platform add` or are you running `ionic cordova platform add`?

Comment: I am running the ionic Cordova platform add.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304065/cordova-error-using-requirecordovamodule-to-load-non-cordova-module-q-is-no

Comment: your cordova version is 9. but u mentioned 8.1.1

Comment: how to change the project Cordova version?