# Error - Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

Running command: node

> C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\mobileionicead\hooks\after_prepare\030_android_splash.js
>
> C:\Users\Windows\Desktop\mobileionicead. Using "requireCordovaModule"
>   to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported. Instead, add this
>   module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Comment: see this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304065/cordova-error-using-requirecordovamodule-to-load-non-cordova-module-q-is-no

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem. You need to downgrade cordova to the version 8.1.2

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm cache clean --force
npm i -g cordova@8.1.2
```